# Play!Framework 2 Java model string field length annotations

Tags: jpa, playframework, annotations, playframework-2.1, ebean

To achieve best performance and validation convenience, which of these annotations are needed for a String field?

database: MySQL

A field to store district name

```
@Column(length=50)  // javax.persistence.Column
```

Is this going to be converted to varchar(50)? Or I need this one specifically:

```
@Column(columnDefinition='varchar(50)')
```

And another two annotations

```
@MaxLength(50) // play.data.validation.Constraints.MaxLength
@Length(max=50) // com.avaje.ebean.validation.Length, is this one useful or not required anyway?
public String districtName;
```

I think I need @Column(length=50) for definition and @MaxLength(50) for validation at same time? Or one of these two will imply the other one automatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, when we mark `String` variable with these annotation:

1. `@javax.persistence.Column(length=50)`
2. `@javax.persistence.Column(columnDefinition='varchar(50)')`. Note: I am use postgreSQL, and this will create column definition with character varying data type
3. `@com.avaje.ebean.validation.Length(50)`

the three annotations above has **the same purpose**. Those will create column definition with `character varying` data type and length of `50` characters on database.

Without the `@Constraint.MaxLength(50)`, you will get exception like below when you entered input value whose length greater than 50:

> **Execution Exception** 
>   `[ValidationException: validation failed for: models.TheModel]`

I think, there should be a way to handle above exception, but honestly I don't know how to do that until now.

---

> #### Advice
>
> My advice for you is to choose one out of the 3 annotations above (It is your preference) with the use of anotation `@Constraint.MaxLength(50)`. For me, it is the easiest and the simplest way, and you can easily make the form using play framework scala-template-helper.